# Are units fixed by automorphisms in higher ramification groups?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> This is another "check out the proof" question. One could close the issue simply by providing a counter-example, or by saying "yes, you are right."

In trying to show the isomorphism $$G_i/G_{i+1}\cong U^{(i)}/U^{(i+1)},$$ I came up with a verisimilar proof that every unit is fixed by $G_i$ for $i\ge0$. I doubt the validity of this proof, though, especially because another proof that I found used the separability to establish that isomorphism, while mine uses not.

> So the proof goes like:
>   Let $\sigma\in G_i$, and $v\in U$ a unit. Write $$v^\sigma=v+u\pi^{i+1}$$ and $$w^\sigma=w+u'\pi^{i+1}$$, with $vw=1$, where $u$ and $u'$ are some algebraic integers. Then we obtain
>   $v^\sigma w^\sigma=1$, i.e. $vu'+uw=0$, and $uu'=0$. But this equation implies immediately that both $u$ and $u'$ are $0$, namely, $v$ is fixed by $\sigma$. So this shows that every unit is fixed by automorphisms in higher ramification groups.

Endowed with this, one can easily show the isomorphism. But I would like to dis-prove it, if it is not true. If, notwithstanding, I am somehow right, and if this question becomes annoying, please inform me so that I can delete it. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. That other proof I have found is [this](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/248APage/handouts/ramgroup.pdf).

Comment: Line -3 of your proof, you only get $vu'+uw+\pi^{i+1}uu'=0$.

Comment: @QiL'8 I see. So could you write an answer providing a counter-example, or, if this is too troublesome, just pointing out this flaw in the reasonings, so that one can close the issue? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose a $\sigma\in G$ fixes every unit $\in U$. For any $x\in \mathfrak m$ (maximal ideal of the local ring), $1+x\in U$, so $1+\sigma(x)=\sigma(1+x)=1+x$ and $\sigma$ fixes evert element of $\mathfrak m$. But $U\cup \mathfrak m$ is the whole ring, so $\sigma=1$.

Comment: Wonderful: it renders my question as a stupid one. Thanks very much for that.  :D